# Обновление Fragment по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Мне нужно сделать перезагрузку Fragment'а по нажатию на кнопку из самого этого фрагмента. (с целью обновления recyclerview) Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

TechnologyFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_technology, container, false);

    //FAB-кнопка
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //перезагрузка
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

fragment_technology.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Technology.TechnologyFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTechnology"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_autorenew_24"
        android:onClick="onClickDone"
        tools:ignore="OnClick,UsingOnClickInXml" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Зачем, если можно обновить recyclerview?

Comment: @Arty Morris ,  а как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Arty Morris , в public void onClick пробовал записывать adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), но не работает

Comment: Этого мало для обновления

Comment: Можно очищать и перезаписывать массив

Comment: @ИльяВеличко покажите код адаптера и то как и где вы меняете данные для списка и как пытаетесь адаптер об изменениях уведомить - надо именно так делать, а не фрагмент удалять и заново добавлять.